# Is there a way to use the Hostname received from DHCP to name the PC after imaging?

Tags: windows, dhcp, hostname

I have been trying to find a way to use the hostname assigned in DHCP to rename a PC after we image it. I found some sample code from Microsoft's web site for C++, but I don't program so it is all Greek to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sysprep is the best option. But after the machine is imaged, how do you determine what the machine will become???

Comment: I think he's relying on DHCP, WDS, or something like that to determine what the desktop becomes.

Answer (score 3):

There's not a built-in function in Windows XP to inherit the computer name from DHCP, as far as I know. It CAN be done with a vbscript, though. I wrote one that you could probably adapt to your purpose that you can find here:

http://www.douglashammond.com/resources/DHCP_hostname_changer.vbs

It's ugly and clunky, and but it worked for me. If you have any feedback or improvements on it, I'd like to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write a custom program, or even VBScript, to set this. But I don't have an example on-hand. But there is no built-in mechanism to do this.